# Query sequence is changing every time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

For Erp version upgrade we copied our database and restored to new one. We altered tables. (Added new columns or changed Width etc. We dropped indexes and recreated). After all we tested new database, caught a situation like this.

We have a query like

```
select top 5 * from table.
```

Old database:  when we run the query continuously, result order not changing

New database:  when we run, order sequence of results changing.

I think there is a clustered index issue but how can I determine and solve it. Any help?

Comment: Your query has no `order by` so there is no guaranteed order in your result. The **only** way to guarantee a specific sort order is to use `order by`

Comment: But old databese came always same

Comment: Then you were lucky. The **only** way to _guarantee_ a specific sort order is to use `order by`

Comment: Please refer to documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 `The order in which rows are returned in a result set are not guaranteed unless an ORDER BY clause is specified.`

Comment: You have learned an unfortunate and terrible lesson in sql (and consulting). Your code is very flawed and this change now exposes one of those flaws. You **must** fix your code and the safe assumption is that there are other flaws waiting to be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use the ORDER BY statement after the TOP statement the database engine does not guarantee the order of the resultset.

SQL Server wants to return qualified rows quickly in some cases and this mechanism called [Row Goals](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/02/sql-plan/setting-and-identifying-row-goals) and most probably your query execution plan uses this mechanism. On the other hand, the clustered index operator includes an **ordered**  attribute and this shows us the retrieved rows are fetched in the ordered manner or not.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Order is not guaranteed unless you use order by.

Old database may have clustered index created on table.  Please check it. But even clustered index does not always guarantee ordering.